# difference in calculating cosine similarity user/item collaborative filtering

Tags: python, numpy, math, cosine-similarity

I'm following a [tutorial](http://blog.ethanrosenthal.com/2015/11/02/intro-to-collaborative-filtering/) for calculating cosine similarity for user-user collaborative filtering and user-item collaborative filtering.

I don't understand why we are using transpose for user similarity denominator while we don't use transpose for item similarity. As follow the python code:

```
ratings = np.zeros((n_users, n_items))
for row in df.itertuples():
    ratings[row[1]-1, row[2]-1] = row[3]

def predict_fast_simple(ratings, similarity, kind='user'):
        if kind == 'user':
            return similarity.dot(ratings) / np.array([np.abs(similarity).sum(axis=1)]).T
        elif kind == 'item':
            return ratings.dot(similarity) / np.array([np.abs(similarity).sum(axis=1)])
```

Can anyone explain to me by example because I don't see a difference between both formula (user-based vs item-based): the denominator is the squared sum of ratings for item i and item j by similar users who rated both items. (for user-based squared sum of ratings of intersection of items rated by both users).

Comment: Look at the shapes and do the math! As we don't see the shapes, we can't do much.

Comment: you mean the code is missing?

Comment: I mean: there are algebraic rules in terms of matrix-matrix-multiplication; mat-vec or even vec-vec operations (column-vector vs. row-vector). Now we often need to transpose something to generate for example an inner-product or whatever... If this is needed in your code, depends on the dimensions / shapes of the data and is a pure math-problem (and some numpy-broadcasting)

Comment: I don't have a good understanding of the math behind and numpy ..

Comment: Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) (especially inner-product) and write your matrices / vectors down (print out the shape if needed). Then do the calculations per hand. And i mean only the calculations about input-dimension * input-dimension = output-dimension (shapes; not values).

Comment: Thanks will try it but another question just raised. here the denominator is not a multiplication but a sum.

Comment: Yes, and the numpy-docs will tell you how the axis-argument works (so that you know what shapes will leave the sum-operation). (you can always print out ```np.array([np.abs(similarity).sum(axis=1)]).shape``` or similar stuff at various places to look what's happening)